# Sharepoint 2013 Online Cloud Deployments

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-deployment

Advice is required here for deploying from a sharepoint 2013 Online development envionrment to the following environments qa, integration and then production.

What is the best way to achieve?

The contents of the site collections :

- Subsites
- Lists(with content, custom content types)
- Customised pages layouts,
- Customised styling
- Customised pages

How can we deployment the whole site collection to a new qa site collection using a deployment tool. We have tried using metalogix and this is continually failing with limited assistance from the company. Microsoft are refusing to provide a backup and restore to another environment.

Therefore we are looking for advice on how to achieve this automated rather than manually creating the content.

As Sharepoint 2013 Online is in the cloud the ability to run powershell is limited and no access the databases. Therefore achieving this is proving to be a real challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Scripted Deployment would be a good option for you. For SharePoint Online this means writing PowerShell with XML configuration and using the SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK (currently v16). The PowerShell is run locally on the developer or administrator’s machine but connects to SharePoint Online using the Client Object Model. Through this script we can deploy most things required for SharePoint Online customization such as:

Master Pages

Page Layouts

Content Types

Display Templates

Term Store Terms

Replication of Production Data

It is desirable to have recent data available in QA to ensure good and valid testing. For this replication it is advisable to use a third-party migration tools. When selecting a tool for this purpose ensure that it can migrate the data faithfully to ensure good testing but also that it can transform data as required. For example, if Production data uses synchronized identities but QA uses Cloud Accounts it will be necessary to perform some transformation.

For More details check :
http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2014/08/how-to-develop-and-deploy-for-sharepoint-online-office-365/